# Authentication credentials were not provided - Django

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble with this error. Tried almost all available solutions but nothing working for me. At frontend side I am using Angular 6 and I am pretty sure it's not error from it. Hoping for a response soon and thanks in advance guys.

**register/url.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserViewSet)


# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    #path('auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('auth/', ObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
]
```

**serialier.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = { 'password' : { 'write_only' : True , 'required':True } }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

**view.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated



class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'register',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

The following error is displayed in the browser's console:

> {“detail”:“Authentication credentials were not provided.”}

Comment: Improved formatting, title and question wording

Answer (score 0):

Your viewset has the `IsAuthenticated` permission class. In other words, an user must be authenticated in order to retrieve, update or even create an instance. Make sure that the appropriate headers are included in your requests.

For example, for a token authentication, as stated by [Django Rest Framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

> For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the
>   Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal
>   "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings. For example:
>
> `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`

In the particular case of an account creation, I'm not sure that it is intended for your application to require an user authentication.